# Set-Content : Stream was not readable - trying to understand why and how to more gracefully fail

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, hosts-file

I have the following line in my PowerShell script

```
(Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Raw) -replace '[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+ local.mywebsite.com',"$ipAddress local.mywebsite.com" | Set-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

(`$ipAddress` is a variable being set elsewhere)

I'm getting admin access by doing this:

```
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin
{
  $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
  $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } else {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated ' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}
```

When I run that script I get the following error:

```
Set-Content : Stream was not readable.
At C:\path\to\setup.ps1:20 char:145
+ ... mywebsite.com" | Set-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:String) [Set-Content], ArgumentE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

I don't understand. Why wouldn't the stream be readable since I'm in admin mode?

Also, when I encounter this error, my hosts file winds up getting emptied so it's not really gracefully failing. The fact that it is getting emptied implies that it is able to write to the hosts file, which is weird since it can't read from it.

If the hosts file can't be read from I'd prefer it if it's contents weren't wiped...

Also, whilst the new Administrator: Windows PowerShell window is open, even tho the script execution has terminated, I am unable to open the hosts file in Notepad, in admin mode, without getting the following error:

```
hosts
The file is in use.
Enter a new name or close the file that's open in another program.
```

Since the PowerShell script returned command back to the CLI idk why it'd still be keeping the file open...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the problem limited to just the `hosts` file? What results do you get from running `icacls` on that file?

Comment: @user1686 - the problem is intermittent but I am having it right now. https://pastebin.com/5rYaMpRX is the output of `icacls c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. As for whether or not it's limited to the hosts file...  idk - the hosts file is the only file I'm trying to modify in this way...

Comment: I get similar errors if One Drive is trying to sync a log file while writes are occurring, but I doubt that would be case for contents in your System32 folder.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest making use of try/catch and `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`:

```
try
{
    $strHosts = (Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Raw)
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($strHosts)) {
        Write-Error -Message "Get-Content hosts empty" -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Unable to read hosts file"
}

try
{
    $strHosts -replace '[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+ local.mywebsite.com',"$ipAddress local.mywebsite.com" | Set-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Unable to write hosts file"
}
```

I also made your regex a bit more robust, allowing any number of whitespace between the IP and the hostname.